# How to access class instance information from setter of nested class instance?

Tags: python

Sorry if the title is confusing or misleading. What I want is a method for updating a log every time a setter is used to update a variable, particularly when the proposed variable change is not allowed. A simple code example best explains what I want. This is for python 3 code.

Let's say my program has a section of input variables 'runvars' with variables `var1` and `var2`. Now from the program context, `var1` must be a boolean. My current method for handling these variables is a class that treats the variables with the property decorator (in file runvars.py):

```
class runvars:

  def __init__(self,var1=1,var2="obsolete"):
    self.__var1 = var1
    self.__var2 = var2

  @property 
  def var1(self):
    return self.__var1

  @property
  def var2(self):
    return self.__var2

  @var1.setter
  def var1(self,val):
    if isinstance(val,bool):
      self.__var1 = val
    else:
      message = "Type: Setter\nVar.:runvars/var1\nErr.: runvars/var1 must be a boolean."
```

'runvars' is just one of many input sections. I want to incorporate it as part of a simulation object which, on top of input parameters like 'runvars' and many other input sections, contains simulation metadata. One of these pieces of data is an error log. For example:

```
import runvars

class simulation:

  def __init__(self,var3=True):
    self.__var3     = var3
    self.__errorLog = []
    self.__runvars  = runvars.runvars()

  @property
  def errorLog(self):
    return self.__errorLog

  @property
  def var3(self):
    return self.__var3

  @property
  def runvars(self):
    return self.__runvars

  @var3.setter
  def var3(self,val):
    if isinstance(val,bool):
      self.__var3 = val
    else:
      self.__errorLog.append("Type: Setter\nVar.: simulation/var3\nErr.: simulation/var3 must be a boolean.")
```

Now if I run

```
mySim = simulation()
print(mySim.var3)
print(mySim.errorLog)
mySim.var3 = "three"
print(mySim.var3)
print(mySim.errorLog)
```

I can see that I screwed up in trying to assign a string to var3 and the change was rejected. I want to be able to do the same for var1.

I apologize if something substantially similar has appeared, I'm just having a hard time formulating a search for this exact problem. Any suggestions, including radical changes to how to organize a program like this, are welcome. I really want to be able to change variables by doing something like `mySim.runvars.subsec1.var1 = value` because there are dozens of logical groupings of input variables. Additionally, I want to keep classes like `runvars` in separate files instead of nesting since otherwise the file would be unmanageably large. Maybe some form of inheritance would helpful here, but I just don't see how it would make sense to do something like make `runvars` a subclass of simulation since I will never instantiate a `runvars` class by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a reference to the errors log list to the instance of `runvars`.

```
class runvars:

  def __init__(self,var1=1,var2="obsolete", errors=[]):
     self.__var1 = var1
     self.__var2 = var2
     self.__errors = errors
 #...
  @var1.setter
  def var1(self,val):
    if isinstance(val,bool):
       self.__var1 = val
    else:
       message = "Type: Setter\nVar.:runvars/var1..."
       self.__errors.append(message)
```

And in `simulation` :

```
 class simulation:

   def __init__(self,var3=True):
     self.__var3     = var3
     self.__errorLog = []
     self.__runvars  = runvars.runvars(errors=self.__errorLog)
```

Since lists are passed as references, if you pass a nonboolean to var1, `self.__errorLog` will be updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Raydel! An easy solution that allows me to keep my code structure.

Comment: Any time, I'm glad to help.